# Изменения не применяются сразу

Tags: android, классы, textview, update, span

Когда я делаю некоторые изменения в View(Конкретно TextView) то чтобы эти изменения применились нужно свернуть приложение и развернуть его снова....можно ли это как-то решить?
Какие изменения?у меня есть класс который наследуется от CharacterStyle...при первом вызове updateDrawState всё нормально...а при последующих возникает вышеописанная проблема...

```
class UpdatableSpan extends CharacterStyle {
    CharacterStyle span;
    TextPaint paint;

    public UpdatableSpan(CharacterStyle Span) {
            span = Span;
    }

    public void updateSpan(CharacterStyle changedSpan) {
        span = changedSpan;
        this.updateDrawState(paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint p1) {
            span.updateDrawState(p1);
            paint = p1;
    }
}
```

Вызов класса и его методов

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final TextView textview1 = findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        final SpannableString str = new SpannableString("Test123");
        final UpdatableSpan span = new UpdatableSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")));
        str.setSpan(span,1,3,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textview1.setText(str);
        textview1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                span.updateSpan(new UnderlineSpan());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: То есть Вы сделали изменения и для того чтобы они применились вызываете `updateDrawState`, я правильно понял? Мне ещё не доводилось использовать этот класс (как-то обходился конкретными спанами) и могу ошибаться, но по-моему этот метод должна дёргать система при обновлении UI, а чтобы вызвать это самое обновление мы должны дёрнуть `view.invalidate()` или `view.postInvalidate()`.

Comment: @pavloff код добавил

Comment: @woesss postInvalidate помогает,но можно ли как-то обойтись без него?

Comment: @woesss ,нет...updateDrawState эти изменения пытается поставить на textview...и у него это получается...нужно лишь както обновить текствью...

Comment: Ну вот для этого и нужно вызвать ему `invalidate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы `View` "заметила" и отобразила изменения нужно намекнуть её об этом методами `invalidate()` или `postInvalidate()`(если не из UI-потока):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final TextView textview1 = findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        final SpannableString str = new SpannableString("Test123");
        final UpdatableSpan span = new UpdatableSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")));
        str.setSpan(span,1,3,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textview1.setText(str);
        textview1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                span.updateSpan(new UnderlineSpan());
                textview1.invalidate();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Тоесть invalidate обязателен?без него никак?

Comment: А чем он Вас так пугает? Может и можно каким-то костыльным способом обойти сам вызов, но по сути вы сделаете то же самое, что и этот метод.

Comment: Ну он меня пугает тем,что его нужно вызывать отдельно...в остальном метод вполне обычный...